# Check the end of a string

Tags: c#, .net, regex

How do I check if a string ends with ***-A*** followed by ***a number***? 

For Example:

**EX-A1** >>> Match. Ends with ***-A*** followed by ***1***

**BLA-A21** >>> Match. Ends with ***-A*** followed by ***21***

**DGUA5** >>> Does not match. Does not end with **-A** followed by **a number**

**CDL-A1A** >>> Does not match. Does not end with **-A** followed by **a number**

What I tried:

```
Regex.Match(myString, "-A\\d+").ToString();
```

The problem with this is that it matches **-A** followed by **a number** anywhere in the string. I need to check if **-A** followed by **a number** is at the end of the string.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `$` to specify end of string:

```
Regex.Match(myString, @"-A\d+$").ToString();
```

See [Start of String and End of String Anchors](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html)

Answer (score 8):

Use an [end anchor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h5181w5w%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#End) (`$`):

```
Regex.Match(myString, "-A\\d+$")
```

This will match the end of the input string (or line, in multiline mode), ensuring that no other characters my follow the match.

Also note, if all you want to do is test whether a string matches a given pattern, you can use [`IsMatch`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.ismatch%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
Regex.IsMatch("EX-A1", "-A\\d+$")   // true
Regex.IsMatch("BLA-A21", "-A\\d+$") // true
Regex.IsMatch("DGUA5", "-A\\d+$")   // false
Regex.IsMatch("CDL-A1A", "-A\\d+$") // false
```

Comment: Should there only be one backslash? If there were 2, Regex will treat `-A\d` as a match.

Comment: @pcnThird No, this code is correct. You need a double slash to encode a single slash in a regular string constant. But C# has both regular and verbatim string constants, so `"-A\\d+$` is the same as `@"-A\d+$"`.

Comment: My bad! I was using rubular.com to test the expressions (which is for Ruby). +1